# What is the regex for "any number doesn't start with 0, but allows spaces in front and behind"

Tags: regex

I have tried the following regex:

```
(([ ]+[1-9](\d+)?+[ ]+)|([ ]+[1-9](\d+)?)|[1-9](\d+)?[ ]+)|([1-9](\d+)?)
```

The strings I am testing against the regex are the following:

"Good" strings that should match:

```
"      3      "
"3"
"3    "
```

"Bad" strings that should fail:

```
"   03     "
"03"
"03    "
```

I have this so far, but the results I get are weird.

Answer (score 4):

Simply you could try the below regex.

```
^\s*[1-9]\d*\s*$
```

Comment: :) I was a bit quicker this time :)

Comment: Pedantic note: this does assume "Arabic" digits for first, but anything in Unicode class Nd for the remaining... but generally better to use the predefined classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC7cP9/2)

Explanation:

- `^` - Beginning of a line/string
- `\s*` - Optional whitespace, any number of repetitions
- `[1-9]` - A digit not equal to `0`
- `[0-9]*` - any number of digits
- `\s*$` - Trailing whitespace before string/line end

This regex will work almost with any regex engine, since not all of them know `\d` (although the majority recognizes this pattern.) Instead of `\s`, you can even use a literal space , but again, that all depends on the regex engine you will choose.

Comment: I updated the demo so as to test exact number of spaces on both sides of the numbers. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
^\s*[1-9]\d*\s*$
```

But some have been faster than me to post.